# SqlConnectionStringBuilder form in .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database-connection

I am wondering how I can add DATA LINK form to my WIN application.
You know those forms where Users can choose on witch SQL server they going to connect
and what type of security they going to use and on wht database.

Something like on this picture
[alt text http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7259/datalink.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/7259/datalink.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through some COM Introp...but then you have to pull in a bunch of Interop assemblies into your project which can be a drag. This code will show the dialog using reflection instead.

```
public static string ShowDialog( IWin32Window owner, 
                                 string connectionString )
{
    Type dlType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "DataLinks", true );
    Type acType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "ADODB.Connection", true );

    object form = Activator.CreateInstance( dlType );
    object connection = Activator.CreateInstance( acType ); 

    acType.InvokeMember( 
        "ConnectionString", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
        null, 
        connection, 
        new object[]{ connectionString } 
        );  
    object result = 
    dlType.InvokeMember( 
        "PromptEdit", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
        null, 
        form, 
        new object[]{ connection } 
        );          
    if( result != null && (bool)result )
        return acType.InvokeMember( 
                    "ConnectionString", 
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                    null, 
                    connection, 
                    new object[]{} ) as string;

    return null;
}
```

This basically translates to the following VB Script

```
form = GetObject( "DataLinks" )
connection = GetOBject( "ADODB.Connection" )
connection.ConnectionString = "existing connection"
form.PromptEdit( connection )
Return connection.ConnectionString
```

Comment: I am again stacked on this issue,
Now I try to send connection sting from app.config file to fill up Initial parameters but I alway get exeption on 
object result=dlType.InvokeMember.
Any advice
Thanx in advice

Comment: Might actually help to open a new question on SO so the entire problem/resolution can be documented for others.

Comment: Thanx on Your attention Ill try yet for while If I couldn't figure it   Then I am going to open new SO, But I am kind shamed asking  over and over people to do code for me.
Best regards

Comment: No shame...we all have to learn somewhere. Alot of this stuff is just down right bizzare and you only learn by banging your head on the wall for days at a time.

Answer (score 1):

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178/prompt-for-database-connection-string).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best choice is to use the code provided from Microsoft here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection.

It is the connection dialog used inside Visual Studio.

However, it only works with registered ADO.NET providers.